# android can't get view position coordinate

Tags: android, position

I have tried to get a position of `textView` using `getTop()` and `getLeft()` methods but they always return me 0. I call this method from onCreate()

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);

    int top = textView.getLeft();
    int left = textView.getLeft();
    int height = textView.getHeight();

    Log.i("top", "top = " + top);
    Log.i("left", "left = " + left);
    Log.i("height", "height = " + height);
```

Comment: The reason you get 0 is because onCreate is called before the view is actually measured for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found answer. Just use `getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener` and inside this method call getLeft, getTop etc.

Answer (score 2):

Once the layout pass is complete, a layout listener will fire. It's not tied to a specific activity lifecycle so you'll have to add an observer to the layout pass.

```
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout()
                {
                    // Now you may get the left/top/etc. 
                    getCoordsFromView(view);
                    // Optionally remove the listener so future layouts don't change the value
                    view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

The textview isn't visible yet at that point. You need to call those **at a later point** (see below documentation) in your activity's lifecycle.

To quote the **[lifecycle documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)**:

> Once the onCreate() finishes execution, the system calls the onStart()
>   and onResume() methods in quick succession. Your activity never
>   resides in the Created or Started states. Technically, the activity
>   **becomes visible to the user** when onStart() is called, but onResume()
>   quickly follows and the activity remains in the Resumed state until
>   something occurs to change that

[image: Some image]